# Magento sample payment module: what is an ENV Request

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway

I'm working to understand the Magento sample payment module.

In the AuthorizationRequest class (https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/blob/master/sample-module-payment-gateway/Gateway/Request/AuthorizationRequest.php) there is a comment

```
/**
 * Builds ENV request
 *
 * @param array $buildSubject
 * @return array
 */
public function build(array $buildSubject)
```

What the heck is an ENV request?

Sorry if this is a non-intelligent question, I'm new to Magento 2

Comment: can any body plz answer this !!